# Writing and saving XML with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to create a XML file and fill it with generated data. Here is a code I have. There is no error but it does not create any file under same folder. It is a AIR Desktop project and if I change it to `FileReference` option that pops up a dialog box and can successfully save.

```
var objects = ["one","two","three"];
var values = ["1", "2", "3"];
var file = new File();
var fileStream = new FileStream();
file = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("ayara.xml");
var myXmlTag = "<ayar>";


for(var lp:int = 0; lp < 1; lp++)
{
    myXmlTag += "<Etkinlik>"
    for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
    {
        myXmlTag += "<" + objects[i] +  ">" + values[i] + "</" + objects[i] + ">";
    }
    myXmlTag += "</Etkinlik>" 
}
myXmlTag += "</ayar>";

var xmlfinal:XML = XML(myXmlTag );
fileStream.openAsync(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fileStream.writeUTF(xmlfinal);
```

Am I missing something or executing things in wrong way? I have checked posts about handling XML files and there is nothing much different from that.

Comment: Your code looks fine. You can check it. If you change `File.applicationStorageDirectory` to `File.desktopDirectory` the file will be saved to the desktop.

Comment: It saves to `user` folder and `usersDocument` folder as well. It would be great to save it in the same folder.